# Get coverage on compiled projects with jacoco using Gradle in Android projects

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I have an Android project (which generates an apk) and uses an SDK. 
In order to use the SDK in my project, I put the following line in build.gradle:

```
compile project(':sdk')
```

Then, I use Jacoco to get coverage report for my tests made in "myproject" project (the sdk has no tests). I've added this line (among others) in build.gradle:

```
def coverageSourceDirs = [
    '../myproject/src/main/java',
    '../sdk/src/main/java'
]
```

but the result is that I get coverage only on "myproject" project, but I get no coverage on the classes of the sdk.

Is it possible to get coverage of lines of the sdk, with tests made on myproject, using jacoco plugin?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using unit tests or non-unit tests? What's sourceSets definitions are for main source code?

Comment: I'm using Espresso to make UI tests

Comment: That's file, but what I was asking is are you running Unit tests written in Expresso / Junit etc (when you do gradle build or gradle test) .. or are you running some Integration/GUI/Acceptance based non-unit tests (written in Expresso) while your application/webservice/project's .war/.ear etc is running behind a Target JVM (Tomcat, JBoss, etc). Secondly, what's the value of "main" source code. I think you need to tell Gradle that, sdk/src/main/java is also the source code of your main/project (including myproject/src/main/java).

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the packages that you want coverage report for, as "includes".

```
def coverageSourceDirs = [**/src/main/java] 
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "connectedAndroidTest") {
     classDirectories = fileTree(
             dir: 'build/intermediates/classes',
             excludes: ['**/R.class',
                        '**/R$*.class',
                        '**/BuildConfig.*',
                        '**/Manifest*.*',
                        '**/*Activity*.*',
                        '**/*Fragment*.*'
             ],
             includes: ['**/path_to_your_app's_package/']
     )
     sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
     additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
     executionData = files('build/jacoco/connectedAndroidTest.exec') }
```

Answer (score 0):

I arrived to a solution.
Currently, i'm testing an sdk inside an external lib (app) and the sdk is compiled and added as dependecy in build.gradle.
In my sdk i'm using dagger for dependecy injection, and in the app butterknife for view injection.
Dagger generates some $$.classes in build dex files,so when you try to run the jacocoTest without exclude the injection modules you have some errores.
So you have to exclude these files.
Also you have to add classes and sources files as main source directories and classes.

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "connectedAndroidTest") {
    description = "Generates Jacoco coverage reports: XML and HTML"
    group = "Reporting"
   jacocoClasspath = project.configurations['androidJacocoAnt']
  // exclude auto-generated classes and tests
    def fileFilter = ['*/$*.class',
                      '**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*',
                      'android/**/*.*','**/*$InjectAdapter.class',
                      '**/*$ModuleAdapter.class',
                      '**/*$ViewInjector*.class']
   def debugTree = fileTree(dir:
            "${project.getRootDir()}/sdk/build/intermediates/classes/debug",excludes:fileFilter
    )
    def mainSrc = "${project.getRootDir()}/sdk/src/main/java"
    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.projectDir, includes: ['**/*.exec', '**/*.ec'])
    // Bit hacky but fixes https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69174.
    // We iterate through the compiled .class tree and rename $$ to $.
    doFirst {
        new File("${project.getRootDir()}/sdk/build/intermediates/classes/debug").eachFileRecurse { file ->
            if (file.name.contains('$$')) {
                file.renameTo(file.path.replace('$$', '$'))
            }
        }
    }
  reports {
        xml {
            enabled = true
            destination = "${project.buildDir}/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml"
        }
        csv.enabled false
        html {
            enabled = true
            destination = "${project.buildDir}/reports/jacoco"
        }
    }

}
```